# How to see the full date on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, big-sur

[image: The menu bar in macOS Catalina, with an expanded clock dropdown that shows the current date.]

With default settings, the clock on macOS Catalina shows the current day of the week and the current time. You can click the clock to reveal the full date.

In the Big Sur update, this dropdown seems to have vanished, instead opening notification center on interaction.

I don't want to see the full date at all times. It takes up space in the dock, and most of the time the full date is not really relevant information. I would prefer to be able to use the old behavior if possible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119915/discussion-on-question-by-cassidy-bandy-how-to-see-the-full-date-on-macos-big-su).

Answer (score 17):

The option is there, `Preferences` -> `Dock & Menu Bar` -> `Clock` and select "Show Date".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In the question I stated that "I'm aware that it is possible to show the date permanently by changing the settings for the clock, but I don't want to always see the date.", so this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @CassidyBandy your question makes less sense the more I ponder what you want to do. ***“I don't want to always see the date. Is there a way to see the full date”*** here is the answer to show it when you want and hide it when you don’t.

Comment: @bmike I don't want to see the date at all times, since it takes up space in the dock. If I want to see the date, I used to be able to click the clock area to show me expanded details. This is no longer possible with Big Sur since they got rid of this menu.

Comment: But that’s not what people reading your question understand @CassidyBandy I’m not arguing that you can’t want this, just pointing out the question and your comment here about dock aren’t entirely clear.

Comment: @bmike I have updated the question so it should be a bit easier to understand now

Answer (score 2):

[Istat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) will do what you want.  Its dropdown shows the full date.  Of course, it is a rather expensive paid app just for showing the full date - but has lots of (too me) essential functionality.

Someone may be able to suggest a simpler widget just for the date.

Answer (score 1):

You can not enable this anymore. I recommend a widget or other way to make it visible if you depended on this in the past.